# .push end´s in "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, store, vuex

I have defined a Vuex store with (actions, state, mutations and getters)

When i add a new todo to my state array in the mutations i got following error:
Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

```
const state = {
  todos: []
}

export default {
  ADD_TODO (state, payload) {
    state.todos.push(payload.todo)
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to use an array with the state?

I also tried this with using an object for todos state which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mutate the state itself, you have to assign a new value to state to mutate it so in your case you can do :

in your component assign your todos from store to a variable like

```
//COMPONENT
let todos = [...this.$store.todos] //or assign from a getter if you have one;
todos.push(newTodo);
addTodo(todos); //call mutation from component and pass your todos array as payload


//STORE
ADD_TODO (state, payload) {
  state.todos = payload;
}
```

Comment: All right...assignment but:

state.todos = [...state.todos, payload.todo];

unfortunately throws  the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a pointer problem for instance if your todo variable comes from a data section :

```
/** Component **/
data () {
  todo : {
    // whatever
  }
},
methods: {
  addTodo () {

    // Will add same todo reference to state list
    // which can cause “Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation 
    // handlers” exception

   ADD_TODO({todo : this.$data.todo}) 

  }
},
```

Instead of passing the entire todos array you could just dereference your todo entry like this before adding to your list :

```
const _todo = Object.assign({}, todo)
ADD_TODO({todo : _todo}) // call store action
```